# Windows Batch: Meaning of a colon in a variable's name

Tags: batch-file, syntax

I have a .bat file that I need to convert into a Linux .sh one.

In this .bat script there si some piece of code I just do not understand and I cannot find proper keywords to search it's meaning.

Here is the code:

```
if not x%VERSION:SNAPSHOT=%==x%VERSION% (
        echo " ....  SNAPSHOT version detected "
        echo VERSION=%VERSION:SNAPSHOT=%%formatdate%_%formattime%
    )
```

My main problem lies with the usage of a ":". What does `%VERSION:SNAPSHOT=% do?`

I also do not know the meaning of the 'x' in `x%VERSION%` or `x%VERSION:SNAPSHOT%`.

Comment: See `set /?` - the colon is used to replace one substring with another after`=`

Comment: The 'x' which is used on both sides of the `==` sign is a dirty hack: it prevents a syntax error in case either side of the `==` sign evaluates to nothing.

Answer (score 8):

The `:` (as well as the `=` at the end of the variable) are used for [string substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace).

In this case, `%VERSION:SNAPSHOT=%` says to take the contents of the variable `%VERSION%` and replace any instance of the string `SNAPSHOT` with nothing.

As Mike said in the comments, the `x` on both sides is used to prevent a syntax error in case `%VERSION%` contains nothing but the string `SNAPSHOT`, which would cause a syntax error. Traditionally, you'll see quotes being used instead of other strings, but this method is perfectly valid.

The entire `if` statement checks to see if `VERSION` contains the substring `SNAPSHOT` and runs its code if it does.